# Is there a reason as to why you would declare a HTML selector with an ID in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

**Edited version of the original**

How is declaring `div#test` different to declaring it as just `#test`? Also can I declare both of the in the same stylesheet i.e.

```
#div test {

}

#test {

}
```

**Original question**

If I were to declare the following style `div#test` how is that different to referencing a `div` element with an ID `test` e.g. `<div id="test">content</div>`

**EDIT**

To clarify what I mean is that how is `div#test` different to just `#test` and then referencing it in the `div` element.

Comment: What's the question exactly?  One is a CSS selector and one is an HTML snippet....

Comment: I don't get your question.  The first part of your sentence describes how you'd refer to such a div in CSS, and the second part is the HTML of the div itself.

Comment: @Chris Farmer - I have edited my question so hopefully I have clarified what I am trying to understand.

Comment: @Ray Toal - I have edited my question so hopefully I have clarified what I am trying to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it makes a sense if you have global css for every page and on one page you add #test to div element and on some other page you add it for p. in such case, even though p has id #test, css rules will not be applied to it if div#test is used instead of #test.

however probably you should consider renaming such conflicting elements, but not always it is possible (for example you are not the only one who works with html and css or some external plugins, whatever). of course it is not good protection, but still, could make sense in some specific cases.

Comment: Right so if I declared `div#test` this would apply only to the `div` element even if I assigned `p` with the id `test`?

Comment: Also does that mean I can have the declaration `div#test` and `#test` in the CSS stylesheet?

Comment: +1 interesting observation plus a warning against using such a technique.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey yes you can have both rules in a stylesheet.  Experiment. :)

Comment: +1 __@mkk:__ Just for clarifying (you explicitily don't tell that), `id` attribute must be unique in a document.

Comment: @Ray Toal - Thanks for confirming I can use both in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

as id must be unique nothing. although in an external stylesheet it may allow readers to know the type of element this applies to.

Comment: Why does it matter the type of element it is referencing if that element has an id of say `test` in this example?

Answer (score 1):

If you use **div#test** in your css, it will look for any ID with the name test, that belongs to a div, as if you just did **#test**, it could be applied to any other element.  It also add's specificity to your selection, and could potentially help those reviewing your code know exactly what you are referring to.

*Example.*

```
#test { margin-top: 10px; }

<ul id="test">
  <li><a href="#">LinkyLink</a></li>
</ul>

div#test { background: blue; }

<div id="test">
    <p>This is jargan!</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.